# how to load page faster by loading widget or image later?

Tags: jquery, html, performance

i have a website who listing the list on the frontpage just like archive page of blogs.
the page have many images in frontpage for many feature the page have.

I want a feature that showing image whenever they focus them not before focus. like [hanselman blog]

when i remove the facebook or twitter widget who i show for every post their then page is only 133KB but if i use Facebook twitter widget then total size is 2.6 MB [yeah 2.6 mb is a size after twitter facebook widget].

I want to do the followign this and sugges me the best i can implment :-

i load the facebook or twitter widget after the page load because i need performance and better page load very fast if i not load them before page load.

i want to show image for post like Hanselman blog hanselman.com/ like if you focus the post then they show you image [not for performace but it's look like glamours ],

are their and good thing you know to this thing. [jQuery readymade script or plugin]

Comment: it's called as lazy loader, you can find the plugin online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Scott's page source code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if (navigator.platform == "iPad") return;
    $("#blog-posts img").not('[src*=theloungenet]').lazyload({
    placeholder : "/blog/scripts/lazyload.gif",
    effect : "fadeIn"
  });
```

});

Is a pluggin called lazyload.